# Meaning of "the vanquishing of something"

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerunds, prepositional-phrases

In this [NPR news excerpt](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=308934760), it says:

> At one point, Shepard has director Ishiro Honda explain why **the vanquishing of Godzilla** feels so sad, and his words sum up brilliantly what gives Godzilla its strange power.

Does **the vanquishing of Godzilla** mean Godzilla wins in some sense?
Since "A vanquished B" means "A beat B" in some sense.

But somehow I think in the original excerpt, It is more reasonable that it means the fact that Godzilla is beaten makes us sad. Since we have some compassion toward him.

What does **the vanquishing of Godzilla** really mean?

Comment: According to [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/of), *of* (sense 3) is used for "saying who or what does something". a) used after nouns that refer to actions for saying who or what does the action; b) used after nouns that refer to actions for saying who or what is affected by the action. I think this one has the sense of 3b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means *the act of vanquishing Godzilla*, so Godzilla loses.

When you convert a full clause like *someone vanquished Godzilla* into a gerund (the *-ing* form here), the object (*Godzilla*) becomes a prepositional object with *of*. That is what happened here:

> someone vanquises Godzilla → the vanquishing of Godzilla

However, there are other constituents that can be converted into an *of* phrase with a gerund:

> Christ comes → the coming of Christ
>
> your mother yells → the yelling of your mother

Here you can see that the subject is *also* turned into an *of* phrase if you turn the verb into a gerund.

So, when you see a gerund with *of*, how do you know what kind of semantic function the *of* phrase has? The answer is that you cannot know, except based on context, e.g., the meaning of the verb, the kind of noun after *of* (is it a person?), the situation, the rest of the story, etc.

With verbs that can take a direct object in a full clause, like *vanquish*, the converted *of* phrase will usually be from a direct object, as in *the vanquishing of Godzilla*; but there is no guarantee.

Comment: To be clear, Does "The hitting of John makes me angry" have both possibility? (John hits something or something hits John.)

Comment: @CYC: Yes, both interpretations are possible. But it is probably more likely to mean that something hits John, because the verb can have a direct object, just like *vanquish*.